# How to sort and order a list using the Java 8 streams API

Tags: java, java-stream

Given the following list of objects:

```java
final List<BusinessUnit> unorderedUnits = Arrays.asList(
            new BusinessUnit("OTHER"),
            new BusinessUnit("BUELL"),
            new BusinessUnit("HARLEY_DAVIDSON"),
            new BusinessUnit("VINTAGE")
        );
```

I am attempting to reorder the above list so that the are in the order "HARLEY_DAVIDSON", "VINTAGE", "BUELL", all other objects in the list.

I have attempted to achieve this with:

```java
unorderedUnits.sort(comparingInt(f -> asList("HARLEY_DAVIDSON", "VINTAGE", "BUELL").indexOf(f.getName())));
```

The result of this:

```java
result.forEach(r -> System.out.println(r.getName()));

OTHER
HARLEY_DAVIDSON
VINTAGE
BUELL
```

Notice that the `OTHER` element comes before the correctly sorted elements.

How do I ensure the `OTHER` element (and any other element) come after the  elements corresponding to the listed property values in the `sort`?

Comment: `indexOf` returns -1 if it's not present in the list

Comment: @Michael Can you elaborate?

Comment: I literally can't. It's a statement which as clear as I can make it.

Comment: `"OTHER"` is not in the list, so `indexOf` returns `-1` and that's why you see it first after sorting the list.

Comment: @MarcoMarchetti Is it possible to have "OTHER" come after instead in this scenario?

Comment: Sure: write a function that returns the index of the element in the list, or, let's say, 42 if the index is -1. And use that function to create your Comparator. Or any other function that returns a number bigger than the others for the other values.

Answer (score 0):

The following `comparator`:

```java
unorderedUnits.sort(comparingInt(n -> ordered.indexOf(n.getName()) == -1 ? ordered.size() : ordered.indexOf(n.getName())));
```

Achieves the output I was looking for:

```
HARLEY_DAVIDSON
VINTAGE
BUELL
OTHER
```